# How to Perspective Transform Image Using Corner Coordinates In Flutter

Tags: flutter, opencv, dart, perspective

I need to **Perspective Transform** (using corner coordinates) document image in my flutter app.

[See Example Here: 4 Point Image Perspective Transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgmby.png)

I have already tried implementing OpenCV C++ Library using dart FFI.

https://medium.com/flutter-community/integrating-c-library-in-a-flutter-app-using-dart-ffi-38a15e16bc14

**Problems in this approach:**

1. Increases App Size
2. Can't Execute Asyncronously (App UI freezes until execution completes)

I have also tried combining these two approaches:
Transform **Image** widget and render widget UI as Image.
https://medium.flutterdevs.com/perspective-in-flutter-904c6cade292

https://medium.com/flutter-community/export-your-widget-to-image-with-flutter-dc7ecfa6bafb

But Renders Image with respect to screen resolution.
For Example:
If Image resoulution is 2000x2000 px and it is taking only 400x400 px on screen, then rendered image will be 400x400 px.

Is there any other performance and size efficient way of doing Perspective Transform of Image using 4 Corner Coordinates ?

Comment: not a crop. cropping doesn't distort the image and only "cuts" horizontally or vertically. -- you need to calculate the homography that expresses this transformation. if you have four pairs of points, OpenCV has getPerspectiveTransform for you

Comment: @christophRackwitz Thanks for correction. I had implemented you suggested method "getPerspectiveTransform" from OpenCV, using Dart FFI (Foreign Function Interface), but It has performance and app size issues with Flutter, as mentioned in Question.

Answer (score 1):

try to use one of this packages
https://pub.dev/packages/document_scanner_flutter
or
https://pub.dev/packages/cunning_document_scanner
or paid packages
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_genius_scan
or
https://pub.dev/packages/scanbot_sdk

Comment: please also give some supporting inforation